# WPF Combobox assigning selectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have an issue related to combobox in WPF

My xaml code for Combo box

```
<ComboBox Name="CertificateComboBox"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="1,59,0,48" IsEnabled="{Binding SecurityEnabled}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CertificatesList}" DisplayMemberPath="CertName" SelectedItem="{Binding Certificate, Mode=TwoWay}" ToolTip="List of SSL certificates. Select a value from the combobox.">
</ComboBox>
```

CertificatesList is a list of CertificateEntry objects

```
public class CertificateEntry
{
    public string CertName { get; set; }
    public string CertHash { get; set; }
    public X509Certificate2 certificte {get; set; }
    public CertificateEntry( X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        certificte = cert;
        if (cert.FriendlyName.Equals(""))
        {
            CertName = cert.Issuer;
        }
        else
        {
            CertName = cert.FriendlyName;
        }
        CertHash = cert.Thumbprint;
    }
    public string ToString()
    {
        return CertName;
    }
}
```

Property SelectedItem Property is

```
public CertificateEntry Certificate
    {
        get
        {                
            return _certificate;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_certificate == value) 
                return;

            _certificate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Certificate");
        }
    }
```

My issue is when i am trying to assign a object to CertificateComboBox.SelectedItem

```
this.CertificateComboBox.SelectedItem = _certificate;
```

where `_certificate` is a `CertificateEntry` Object
Its not taking the value

In the add watch after the above call is `null

```
this.CertificateComboBox.SelectedItem = null
```

the assignment is not happening, 
I want to show the assigned certificate as the default selected value in combobox, which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

you can only set the selected Item to an object that is in your ItemsSource, is this the case?

Regards
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

I am confused...

You created property `Certificate` for your combo's selected item but you assign its `SelectedItem` property like that:

```
this.CertificateComboBox.SelectedItem = _certificate;
```

where probably `_certicate` is null.

I think you just need to do

```
Certificate = some value
```

where some value is a valid `CertificateEntry` that belongs to your items source.

Comment: _certicate is a Certificate Object which is not null

Comment: @Hari _certificate is the name of the variable your are using for your Certificate property which is binded to your combo's SelectedItem. As I tried to explain don't use _cerficate directly. Just set Certificate property with a value, NOT _certificate, and it will work.